# Date conversion of the format containing "e" in the milliseconds

Tags: android, android-studio, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

How to convert the **"1.5332445E9"** in date and time?

Till now i have tried

```
private String getDate(long time) {
            Date date = new Date(time);
            return Utils.getFormattedDate(date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        }
public static String getFormattedDate(Date date, String desiredFormat) {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(desiredFormat);
                dateFormat.format(date);
                return dateFormat.format(date);
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://ideone.com/udUvW5

Comment: thanks @Selvin it worked like a charm...simple and elegant

Comment: As an aside the `Date` class is long outdated and poorly designed, and `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome. You may want to consider using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. On not brand new Android use it through [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/blob/master/build.gradle).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to use the long value and not this formatted string

Answer (score 0):

If this string represents miliseconds, get the date like this:

```
String s = "1.5332445E9";
Double doubleMils = 0.0;
try {
    doubleMils = Double.parseDouble(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Long longMils = doubleMils.longValue();

Date date = new Date(longMils);
```

Now you can format `date` as you like.